# Как вывести записи с БД в обратном порядке с n-ой записи SQL?

Tags: php, sql, сортировка, order

Допустим есть 20(id) записей в бд. Мне нужно с 16-ой(id) записи вывести 5 записей в обратном порядке. Т.е 16,15,14,13,12. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Order by, limit, offset.

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 4 LIMIT 5
```

Вот только `OFFSET` вам нужно будет вычислять в зависимости от общего количества записей

Comment: кажется человеку нужно просто вывести 5 запсией

Comment: а вообще, например для mysql имеет место быт следующее утверждение: "_Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result **because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows**._"

Comment: @teran пожалуй, Вы правы. Изменил ответ.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! "Где мне взять денег? Да в сейфе. Только надо будет ключ от сейфа где-нибудь найти"

Comment: @Ипатьев Вопрос поставлен о ровно 20 записях. И если применять вашу аналогию, то "Код сейфа 0351, но завтра может измениться "

Comment: омг, детский сад, штаны на лямках. "я не знаю как ответить на вопрос, зато вот какую я придумал отмазку"